# Swift 3: How can I add the buttons on the UIWeb View

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

I am doing a project and I want to add 6 buttons on the webview , but whenever I am trying to add a button, the app doesnot show this button.

Any suggestion, help really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: what errors you getting

Answer (score 0):

**Try This-**

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ratingButtonTapped), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.profileVIew.addSubview(button)

func ratingButtonTapped(){
    print("Button pressed")
}
```

Comment: And if you want to add button on webView, Do like so-

Comment: `@IBOutlet var webVIew: UIWebView!`

Comment: And write addSubView method in  viewDidLoad()-

Comment: `self.webVIew.addSubview(button)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you how to do this in code without using storyboards. Put his in your **view controller class**

```
 var setupButton: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .system)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161, a: 256)
            button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button

        }()
```

then in your **viewDidLoad()** function put

```
view.addSubview(setupButton)
myButton()
```

then outside of viewDidLoad() put

```
func myButton() {

setupButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
setupButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
setupButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
setupButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true }


func handleRegister {
      #your action here 
}
```

Comment: Hi @SamuelTeferraI am being trying for last  few weeks, can you please help me? Thanks.